# Searching for Strings with indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url, search, indexof

I'm still having problems with understanding the indexOf functionality correctly, or there is something else that I can't see.

I'm currently using this for loop to search for text strings/segments in a URL:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    element = links[i];
    if(element.href.indexOf(segment) !== -1) {
        return true; 
      }
```

If the URL is for example: `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text?some&parameters` and `segment = "this_is_my_text"`it works just fine.

However, if the URL looks like this: `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text`and `segment = "this_is_my_text"`the segment/string is not found and the function (around this for loop) returns false and not true.

What am I doing wrong? I really can't see it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Me neither. Could you make a jsfiddle or a SO snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I tested it like this: `alert("http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text".indexOf("this_is_my_text"));` and it alerted 26, and 26 is still bigger than -1, so this works on my end. `console.log()` all values if possible and see if any of them is not found. And try `element.getAttribute("href")` to be safe.

Comment: Are you sure that `href` is not `undefined` in your element? Because what you have should work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hkwprh2d/

In reality I need the `href` though as the URLs will come from a website via jQuery: `links = $(".listing_row_link");`

I can find all results in URLs like `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text?some&parameters` but not in URLs like `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text` - it's really weird

Comment: @xqz313 Well I'm testing your own fiddle with both urls and I find it both times.

Comment: @xqz313 Here is your fiddle updated (i've included jquery and I'm searching all links for that segment and I'm getting 2 results): http://jsfiddle.net/hkwprh2d/1/

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Yeah, it seems like there is a different problem :/ Too bad I can't post more of the real code. But now I'm almost 100% sure it has to be something different and i'll keep looking for other logical errors. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @xqz313 Cool, I'm glad we helped a bit.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov: Found the solution, my loop was too fast and finsihed searching before the data was received via JSON. If I add 500 ms delay it works just fine lol.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/en50c13z/ :

```
var u1 = 'http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text?some&parameters and segment = "this_is_my_text"';
var u2 = 'http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_textand segment = "this_is_my_text"';

    if(u2.indexOf('segment') !== -1) {
        return alert('found'); 
      }
```

I just added '' in the if statement around 'segment' and it is working in both cases now, before this edit both were not working

Comment: Works without " too in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/hkwprh2d/

In reality I need the `href` though as the URLs will come from a website via jQuery: `links = $(".listing_row_link");`

I can find all results in URLs like `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text?some&parameters` but not in URLs like `http://www.anywebsite.com/this_is_my_text` - it's really weird

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Code was right, data from website was received too slow.